# How get the data from nested array in select tag

Tags: laravel, select, pivot

I struggling get data from pivot database in select tag in laravel.

It's a nested array and pivot table.

No idea how to get the value from database.

normally it can get value from normal table look like this.

```
<option value="{{ $food}}" {{ (old("recommended_food") == $food ? "selected":"") }}>{{ $food }}</option>
```

After i save the data, the data format look like

```
[ 
 1 => ['someValue', 'someValue', 'someValue'],
 2 => ['someValue', 'someValue', null]
]
```

## Try 1

```
<select name="show_lyric_slide_masters_displays[{{ $slide->id }}][{{ $display->id }}]">
  @foreach($masters as $id => $master)
   <option {{ in_array($id, old("show_lyric_slide_masters_displays[" . $slide->id . "][" . $display->id . "]")) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{$id}}">{{ $master }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

## Try 2

```
<option {{ old("show_lyric_slide_masters_displays") == $id ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{$id}}">{{ $master }}</option>
```

is it i didn't point correctly in the data?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `== 1 ? '' : '1'` in the option?

Comment: sorry, that is my testing. accidentally in my copy.

Comment: In your model please add like this `return $this->yourRelation('Your Model')->withPivot('your_table_id');`

Comment: yes. i did it in my class model.

Comment: `dd($yourResult)` and see that is it `pivot_id` exist there??

Comment: i can get a pivot data return, it is an array. i wandering how to apply it in my old() method correctly. Should i use groupBy?